# RegEx to capture a Pascal procedure's body

Tags: regex, pascal, regex-recursion

I'm trying to write a RegEx to capture a Pascal procedure's body. My biggest problem so far is capturing a procedure which has a nested procedure inside.

Test string:

```
Test

procedure A;
   procedure B; 
   begin
   end;
begin
   if True then
   begin
   end;
end;

procedure C;
begin
   if True then
   begin
   end;
end;
```

The following RegEx captures the body of the procedure A successfully:
`/procedure A(?:(?!\nbegin)[\s\S])*\n(begin(?:(?!begin|end;)[\s\S]|(?1))*end;)/g`

It avoids the inner procedure by matching everything until it finds a "begin" with no indentation, then it uses recursion to find the matching "end". The problem is that it works on the premise that the code will be properly formatted, which is not something I can count on (and if I could, then I wouldn't even need recursion, just match until it finds an "end" with no indentation as well).

String it should work on too:

```
Test

procedure a;
procedure b; 
begin
end;
begin
if True then
begin
end;
end;

procedure c;
begin
if True then
begin
end;
end;
```

Desired match:

```
procedure a;
procedure b; 
begin
end;
begin
if True then
begin
end;
end;
```

After hours trying to figure out a solution, I couldn't come up with one that works with an arbitrary number of inner procedures and inner begins/ends. Do you guys have any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: Try `procedure A(?:(?!begin|end;)[\s\S])*(?:\s+(?:begin[\s\S]*?end;))+`, see https://regex101.com/r/N5GPaw/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the regex you've sent doesn't match until the last "end;" in the procedure, which could be fixed by adding "\send;" in the end. The problem is that the input could have an arbitrary number of inner procedures and inner begins/ends, which should be balanced to match one properly closing the procedure's body,

Comment: Ok, `procedure A(?:(?!begin|end;)[\s\S])*(?:\s+(begin(?:(?!begin|end;)[\s\S]|(?1))*end;))+` - https://regex101.com/r/N5GPaw/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That works with one inner procedure and without one, but breaks with two or more, see https://regex101.com/r/9WXgeS/1 . The RegEx I want would be able to match any pascal procedure, but now, after better studying the requirements for a proper match, I don't think RegEx is the right tool for it (or if it could even do it).

Comment: It is possible, see https://regex101.com/r/3sKJoU/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?=procedure A;)(procedure \w+;\s*(?:(?!procedure|begin|end;)[\s\S]|(?1))*(begin(?:(?!begin|end;)[\s\S]|(?2))*end;))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3sKJoU/1).

*Details*:

- `(?=procedure A;)` - the current position must be followed with `procedure A;` text
- `(` - Group 1 start:

  - `procedure \w+;` - `procedure` , one or more word chars, `;`
  - `\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?:(?!procedure|begin|end;)[\s\S]|(?1))*` - zero or more repetitions of

    - `(?!procedure|begin|end;)[\s\S]` - any char other that does not start the `procedure`, `begin` or `end;` char sequence
    - `|` - or
    - `(?1)` - regex subroutine recursing Group 1 pattern
  - `(begin(?:(?!begin|end;)[\s\S]|(?2))*end;)` - Group 2:

    - `begin` - `begin` string
    - `(?:(?!begin|end;)[\s\S]|(?2))*` - zero or more repetitions of any char that does not start the `begin` or `end;` char sequence, or Group 2
    - `end;` - `end;` string
- `)` - end of Group 1.